# How to add ArgoCD dex.config from argo App yaml Helm params?

Tags: argocd

In a self-managed ArgoCD the ArgoCD itself is defined as an application installed as a Helm chart with parameters.

How to add dex.config into Helm parameters inside application definition?

This does NOT work!

Here come en error that **dex.config** comes as a map not as a string.

```yaml
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
metadata:
  name: argocd
  namespace: argocd
spec:
  project: argocd
  source:
    chart: argo-cd
    repoURL: https://argoproj.github.io/argo-helm
    targetRevision: 5.19.1
    helm:
      parameters:
       - name: configs.cm."timeout\.reconciliation"
         value: "120s"
       - name: configs.cm."dex\.config"
         value: |
         logger:
           level: debug
           format: json
         connectors:
         - type: saml
           id: saml
           name: AzureAD
           config:
             entityIssuer: https://argocd.example.com/api/dex/callback
             ssoURL: https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxx/saml2
             caData: |
               ...
             redirectURI: https://argocd.example.com/api/dex/callback
             usernameAttr: email
             emailAttr: email
             groupsAttr: Group

  destination:
    server: https://kubernetes.default.svc
    namespace: argocd
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to use multi-sources application feature of ArgoCD.

1. create a ArgoCD helm chart `values.yaml` file with **dex** configuration
2. put `values.yaml` in a git repo
3. point the ArgoCD application source definition to it
4. point second source to the ArgoCD helm chart and use `valueFiles`

Example:

```yaml
kind: Application
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
metadata:
  name: argocd
  namespace: argocd
  finalizers: [ resources-finalizer.argocd.argoproj.io ]
spec:
  project: argocd-platform
  sources:
    - repoURL: https://argoproj.github.io/argo-helm
      chart: argo-cd
      targetRevision: 5.43.5
      helm:
        valueFiles:
        - $values/environments/test/argocd.yaml
    - repoURL: https://mygit.com/config.git
      targetRevision: HEAD
      ref: values
  destination:
    server: https://kubernetes.default.svc
    namespace: argocd
  syncPolicy:
    automated:
      selfHeal: true
      prune: true
      allowEmpty: true
    syncOptions:
      - CreateNamespace=true
```